# Select all and give random output (Random sorted output)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

I have a table looking something like this

```
ID Name City 
-------------
0  asd  sda
1  hrs  gsh
2  ghd  0
3  hsa  0
.
.
```

How could I return city != '0' in random order and then city = '0' in random order?

Comment: What database are you using? Do you have to get the data returned in random order, or can you shuffle it once it's returned?

Comment: I have a MS SQL 2008 server. The idea is that first I want to output everything that I have info about in a random order and then the rest in a random order. This way I will have a lower priority on places missing some info but still return them in random order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server (RAND gives *same* value for all rows in SQL Server)

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN City <> '0' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
    NEWID()
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your DBMS supports a RAND function that returns a different random number for each row in your result set:

```
SELECT ID, Name, City
  FROM SomethingLikeThis
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN City = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, RAND();
```

Comment: @gbn: All the world is not using SQL Server, and the questioner had not said which DBMS he is using when I answered. If the function called RAND() is so deterministic (non-random) that it gives the same answer for each row, one is left wondering what its use is. However, there are probably other functions that do manage to produce random outputs, or you can probably write a stored procedure that does so, and the general thrust of my answer remains valid: order by two pseudo-columns, one so that named cities come before numbered ones, the other that the order within the big groups is random.

Comment: Rand evaluated once *per query* is not "deterministic". I commented because your answer had an upvote otherwise I'd have not bothered. SQL Server has the same per query evaluation for other non-deterministic functions too like getdate. Newid is evaluated per row because it is statistically unique